# Consecutive next value into new column pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i have a dataframe

```
id    value
 v1      100
 v1      200
 v1      300
 v1      400
 v2      500
 v2      600
 v2      700
 v3      800
 v3      900
```

i am looking to transform dataframe into new dataframe df2:

```
id   val1    val2
v1     100     200
v1     200     300
v1     300     400
v1     400     100
v2     500     600
v2     600     700
v2     700     500
v3     800     900
v3     900     800
```

i.e shifting the next consecutive value in next column and also kind of grouping by id's,

i tried using df.shift() , but not working.

Is there any alternative to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We want to use [**`np.roll`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) to accomplish the task within groups.  By using `transform`, we bypass getting hung up with the within group index.

```
df.groupby('id').value.transform(np.roll, shift=-1)

0    200
1    300
2    400
3    100
4    600
5    700
6    500
7    900
8    800
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

---

We can add a new column to a copy of `df` with `assign`

```
df.assign(val2=df.groupby('id').value.transform(np.roll, shift=-1))

   id  value  val2
0  v1    100   200
1  v1    200   300
2  v1    300   400
3  v1    400   100
4  v2    500   600
5  v2    600   700
6  v2    700   500
7  v3    800   900
8  v3    900   800
```

Or add a new column directly to `df` in place

```
df['val2'] = df.groupby('id').value.transform(np.roll, shift=-1)

df

   id  value  val2
0  v1    100   200
1  v1    200   300
2  v1    300   400
3  v1    400   100
4  v2    500   600
5  v2    600   700
6  v2    700   500
7  v3    800   900
8  v3    900   800
```

Comment: Sir, my id column is not integer type, see my edited dataframe. While running df.groupby().value  , your first line of code, i am getting error : `'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'value'`

Comment: @SRingne that should not affect the result at all.  That error is an indication that the column named `'value'` isn't in `df`.  Pleas verify that it is or isn't.

Comment: working! actually i misspelled the column name! Thanks a ton!

Comment: @SRingne glad we could help.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need [`numpy.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
df['val2'] = df.groupby('id')['value'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.roll(x, -1))).values
print (df)
   id  value  val2
0   1    100   200
1   1    200   300
2   1    300   400
3   1    400   100
4   2    500   600
5   2    600   700
6   2    700   500
7   3    800   900
8   3    900   800
```

Comment: the id column is not an integer. please see edit.
i am getting error: `incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`

Comment: Sir it gives the error mentioned above.  `type(df['id'][0]) = 'str' and type(df['value'][0]) = numpy.int64`

Comment: Yes, if no `values` in the end, I get same error. But with `.values` I  get no error. But maybe some bug...